# How can I show light logo in dark mode?

Tags: javascript

I am working on dark mode. Works successfully. There are two types of logos in the script: light and dark. But there is no logo in my css files. I'm getting the logos dynamically. I want to show the light logo in the dark mode. When I switch to dark mode, I also want the light logo to be active. I did a lot of research and trials, but I couldn't get any results. I am not familiar with javascript. I will be happy to any help.

[image]

This is what I aim to happen.
[image]

menu.php
(light logo:`<?=$setlogo?>` , dark logo:`<?=$setlogow?>`

(Maybe i should write a condition here. to check if it goes into dark mode. but this process happens in javascript. How can I check the condition in javascript in php?)

```
<div class="navbar-brand">
    <a href="<?=SITE?>"><img src="<?=SITE?>../images/<?=$setlogo?>" alt="<?=$sitename?>" class="img-fluid logo"></a>
</div>
```

My css links:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" title="light" href="<?=SITE?>assets/css/site.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" title="dark" href="<?=SITE?>assets/css/site-dark.min.css">
```

my js:

```
function switchMode() {

  var mode = document.getElementById("themeSwitch"); 

  if (mode.checked) {
    setActiveStyleSheet('dark');
    localStorage.setItem("ex_mode", "dark");
     
  } else {
    setActiveStyleSheet('light');
    localStorage.setItem("ex_mode", "light");
  }
}
```

and get call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
     setActiveStyleSheet(localStorage.getItem('ex_mode') ? localStorage.getItem('ex_mode') :"light" );
     document.getElementById("themeSwitch").checked = localStorage.getItem('ex_mode')=="dark"  ? true:false ;
 });
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `opacity`?

Comment: Two image tags or css with background image

Answer (score 1):

Two images:

```
<div class="navbar-brand">
   <a href="">
     <img class="light" src="..." />
     <img class="dark" src="..." />
   </a>
</div>
```

light css:

```
.navbar-brand img { display: none; }
.navbar-brand img.light { display: inline-block; }
```

dark css:

```
.navbar-brand img { display: none; }
.navbar-brand img.dark { display: inline-block; }
```

Or just use a background image, going to have to add a few more styles to make sure the whole image appears

```
.navbar-brand a {
  background-image: url('light');
}
```

Or if you make the background transparent on the image, you could use `filter: invert(1);` in the CSS to flip the color.

```css
img {
   filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/300">
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I believe the logo change should be subject to the transition to dark mode. I'm thinking about how to do this.

Comment: "the logo change should be subject to the transition to dark mode" What does that mean?? It will change when you flip the CSS file of the page.....

Comment: I mean that, the logos are not in the css file. I'm dynamically getting it from the database.

Comment: So the two image solution will work.... Just have to put both of them on the page....

Comment: This is like a hack of sorts. It didn't sound like a professional approach.

Comment: Well if you are swapping out the image on the fly you are doing to see a flash. Not sure what is worse. Ideally you store the value on the server and the server returns the image that is needed.

Comment: @burakios There are generally 2 ways to do theming. 1) Let the server know about the theme you are using so only relevant assets are served. 2) Let the server serve all assets and handle theming on the client. - You are currently using 2, because the server serves both stylesheets. Instead of two elements you could also serve all asset data, but only create a single element for each asset. Then let the client manage that single element using the provided data.

Comment: ^ As an example say the server provides the data `[{selector: ".theme.stylesheet", light: {href: "..."}, dark: {href: "..."}}, {selector: ".theme.brand-logo", light: {src: "..."}, dark: {src: "..."}}]` say this data is saved in `themeData` and the current theme is saved in `theme`. With the above you can now do `themeData.forEach(({selector, ...themes}) => $(selector).attr(themes[theme]))` to update all asset related elements. I am using jQuery here to simplify the comment code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but i have to solve this with the above existing codes.